# Multiple different RabbitMQ connections within single app

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a .net-core service that uses MassTransit to listen on a queue. It takes a message, does all the work and in the end it should publish a different message using another connection (different host, login etc.).
I've added a second bus like in MassTransit MultiBus example (https://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html)

```
services.AddMassTransit<ISecondBus>()
```

However I can't figure out how to correctly access this new bus from my controller. I could use `AddConsumer()` on the second bus but then I have no idea how to fire its `Consume()` method. As far as I understand a consumer is someone who waits for incoming messages, but I need to just do the publish without any additional layers of complexity.
Any tips on how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish on the second bus, from a consumer on the first bus, you need to add `ISecondBus` as a dependency on the consumer. Then, you can use that bus to publish messages on the second bus.

```cs
public class MyConsumer :
    IConsumer<Message>
{
    public MyConsumer(ISecondBus secondBus)
    { 
        _secondBus = secondBus;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<Message> context)
    {
        // ...

        await _secondBus.Publish(new SomeEvent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [MultiBus](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/containers/multibus.html#multibus) feature.

It requires you to create an interface either for each bus instance or for those that aren't the default one, and configure them separately.

Comment: I've already added a second bus with a different interface. The main question is how can I access this additional bus in order to publish something.